# Save PHP code to file using fwrite

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, fwrite

I'm having a little problem with a script I'm working on, and this is what I'm running into:

First of all a bit about how the script works. It actually uses WordPress (it's a plugin) and it makes dynamic pages based on various settings they can change in the backend. I'm adding an Export to HTML feature where they can make a static version of that page after they have already created the page in the plugin.

In this exported page I need it to save a PHP function at the top of the file, and another one somewhere else in the page. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$fbscript=file_get_contents('fbscript.txt');
$newcontent=str_replace('<!-- dont erase this line -->',$fbscript,$newcontent);
$fbscript2=file_get_contents('fbscript2.txt');
$newcontent=str_replace('<!-- dont erase this line 2 -->',$fbscript2,$newcontent);
```

The 2 `dont erase this line` things are somewhere in the dynamic pages where it needs to put the scripts. This is what is showing up somewhere in the exported page:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: signed_request in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\easyfanpagedesign\default.theme\htmlpost-31345.php</b> on line <b>82</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\easyfanpagedesign\default.theme\htmlpost-31345.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

So I guess what I'm really trying to ask is how can I save a file using fwrite with a `.php` extension and have a php script inside the saved file. This is an example of the php script I'm trying to add to the page saved using fwrite (Facebook's PHP SDK):

```
<?php
function parsePageSignedRequesttt($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    return null;
  }
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    return null;
  }
  return $data;
}
function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
?>
```

This is my entire export.php file which does everything:

```
<?php
$content=$_POST['efpd_page_content'];
$uistyle=$_POST['efpd_ui_style'];
$app_id=$_POST['efpd_appid'];
$the_fscripts=$_POST['efpd_fscripts'];
$the_hscripts=$_POST['efpd_hscripts'];
$bgstuff=$_POST['efpd_bgstuff'];
$jquery=$_POST['efpd_jquery'];
$jqueryui=$_POST['efpd_jqueryui'];
$cycle=$_POST['efpd_cycle'];
$copytext=$_POST['efpd_copytext'];
$affstr=$_POST['efpd_affstr'];
$the_style=$_POST['efpd_style'];
$the_gwf=$_POST['efpd_gwfstyle'];
$secret=$_POST['efpd_secret'];

if(empty($secret)){$secret=999999;}

$newcontent=file_get_contents($_POST['efpd_refurl']);

$fbscript=file_get_contents('fbscript.txt');
$newcontent=str_replace('<!-- dont erase this line -->',$fbscript,$newcontent);
$fbscript2=file_get_contents('fbscript2.txt');
$newcontent=str_replace('<!-- dont erase this line 2 -->',$fbscript2,$newcontent);
$newcontent=str_replace('THE_SECRET',$secret,$newcontent);

//die(var_dump($newcontent));

$int=rand(1,99999);
$savefile = "htmlpost-$int.php";
$handle = fopen($savefile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($handle,$newcontent);
fclose($handle);
echo "<a href='$savefile'>Right Click &gt; Save As to download the generated HTML page.</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code must be `$_REQUEST['signed_request']`, right?

Comment: Yeah that is in the second script that's added in the middle of the page (fbscript2.txt)

Comment: Ok, that is what is causing these errors that show up - because that page seems to be intended to be an app on facebook and you don't actually run it there (by now?).

Comment: I'm trying to get it to actually save exactly that in the file, not to run the script at all. Just to save it to a file with fwrite. So that page can be put on a server and ran on facebook.

Comment: where is your save code, and where is your export code?

Comment: @gview I updated my question with `export.php`'s code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is that you can not reference a php file in that way, because the server will parse it.  Have a seperate script that sets the header and make this the target of your link.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.php"');
readfile('filename.php');
exit;
```

Comment: You could forgo the link entirely and just have the code I provided occur at the end of the script.  You have to be sure that you don't output anything prior so that the headers are not sent until the end.

Comment: Where does this go right before the fwrite or somewhere else?

Comment: No it would be after you wrote and closed the file.  readfile will read it back out again and return the contents to the buffer.  Substitute your $savefile variable where I had filename.php.

Comment: Ohh ok that makes sense now that I tried it and see what it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that you've updated your question the solution is pretty clear:

You get those results when you do what your link says, right? You right-click on that link and do "Save as.." - but you don't really save the php code but just what the server outputs as the php code first gets executed by the server.

Comment: Yeah but I'm actually just trying to get it to save the PHP code, not to execute it.

Comment: The PHP Code is in the file, but you just can't save it to your local drive that way. See gview's answer for some helpful code to solve that problem!